# Redner HTML.TextBoxFor name as pascal case

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I render a

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Email )
```

With this property

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

The HTML has this attribute

```
name="Email"
```

How can I make it output pascal case so it sets attributes accordingly?

Comment: Why? Won't that break the default ModelBinder, as that is case-sensitive? Anyway, see duplicate: no, not the default TextBoxFor, create your own helper.

Comment: Great exactly what I wanted to hear.